# What can a human do in a short time (10-20 years) to improve their genome?

Tags: genetics, genomes

I'm wondering **what can I do to make my children receive better genes?**

For example, can fitness, cold showering, studying etc. change my hereditary material and affect my children?

Comment: Reproduce with someone whom you think has "better" genes than you. There is nothing you can do for your own genes.

Comment: You could also reproduce a whole lot, and cull the children who end up with worse genes, preserving only those with the best genes. Some species, like certain birds, do this by allowing their offspring to fight for food, only feeding their stronger offspring. Of course this is easier if you have multiple offspring at once. IANAL but you might want to check whether this is legal in your jurisdiction before proceeding.

Comment: @BryanKrause: despite the ethics debate over designer humans, well-intentioned genetic engineering sounds much more humane and efficient than your solution.

Comment: @kmm Couldn't epigenetics be affected within one's life?

Comment: There is evidence that epigenetic marks can be inherited, though last I checked it was still somewhat controversial.

I recall a paper where obese parents were (epi)genetically more likely to have obese children. Therefore, if you spend your life taking care of your health, it's likely that your children may benefit from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No amount of lifestyle practice will change your germline (heritable) genome.

However there were 2 recent articles where researchers experimentally fixed dangerous genetic defects in embryos using CRISPR-Cas9 which could form the basis of future tech that corrects all known dangerous genetic diseases.

Bear in mind that the idea of "designer humans" (using gene-editing to make more perfect humans rather than just fixing serious hereditary problems) remains incredibly controversial and bitterly contested/debated (and illegal in most Western nations). Expect it to remain that way over the next 10 years.

If you want perfect offspring and aren't up to waiting, you might consider diving into robotics and AI instead and build a robot. That way, if it has any problems, you can always order new parts or provide tech support.